# Is there any performance concern if too many parameter in a constructor?

Tags: java

I know it is not good design and I would rather use setter/getter if there is the choice. but I am writing a `JPA` entity and need this constructor for `JPQL` purpose, so in short I have to use constructors to initiate values for fields and embedded entities as well.

So I have to make about `40` parameters in the entity's constructors and have to let JPA use the constructor pretty frequently. I have been search online and haven't found anything stating that over-sized parameter list in java constructor may cause performance issue, but may be I didn't do enough homework.

So any advice is appreciated, performance is the only concern.
thanks

Comment: You should look into the `Builder` pattern

Comment: I think it will affect the performance of anyone who has to read your code.  :) :)

Comment: There is a performance hit, but I don't know how large. When the method is called, the JVM has to store each of its arguments in the "local variable array" of the frame for the method, even if most of the arguments will not be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> performance is the only concern

The issues with oversized parameter lists have practically nothing to do with performance--your performance will probably be as good or better than if you used setter methods to set up your object. Of course, as in all performance-related cases, the best advice is to try it, and benchmark it, and see if you can measure any difference. If this isn't a part of your code that you've identified as slowing things down, then performance *shouldn't* be a concern for you at all, much less your *only* concern.

However, having any method or constructor with such a large list of parameters makes your code unmaintainable and error-prone, and you should be seeking other options purely for the sake of code maintainability.

Comment: Thank you. yes it is not supposed to have so many parameters, it is very specific cases(Construct the object by a JPA query has to initiate all embedded fields in the class too..).

Answer (score 0):

To simplify constructing an object, you should use a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern:

```
public class SomeComplexClass

    public static class SomeComplexClassBuilder {

        /* fields to set for the constructor */

        /* getters and setters for those fields*/

        public SomeComplexClass build() {
            //verify the fields are all correct for the object
            return new SomeComplexClass(/* pass the necessary fields*/);
        }

    }

    private SomeComplexClass(/*arguments*/) {...}

}
```

Then you can construct using the builder:

```
SomeComplexClass obj = new SomeComplexClass.SomeComplexClassBuilder()
                                           .setSomething(/*argument*/)
                                           .setAnother(/*argument*/)
                                           .build();
```

You can chain the methods to return the builder object for doing all that:

```
public SomeComplexClassBuilder setField(Object argument) {
    this.argument = argument;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Does this address the JPA/JPQL issues that the OP mentions? Is there a way to make these frameworks leverage these builders?

Comment: The Builder pattern (I would imagine) is fairly independent from any framework unless it requires a specific constructor (in which you can just use a public one _and_ the builder). There's no noticable performance issue with either that I'm aware of, this helps to reduce errors in future code writing.

Comment: A builder might reduce the number of parameters within a constructor, but really it won't reduce them.  In fact, a builder probably will cause slower performance due to all the stack thrashing.  The real issue of "why so many fields" typically is just hidden with a builder, unless many of the fields are _related_, in which case, one could group them by the building stanzas.

Comment: @Rogue Thank you for the thorough explanation and coding sample, the situation here is constructor is unavoidable and has to initiate the object with one method, that really limit the choice. Basically the JPQL pattern is like `SELECT new DarnConstructor(<parameter list>) FROM BIGTABLE;` so JAVA design pattern does not apply.... But I am taking note of your advice, very helpful in general cases.

Comment: I don't see the advantages of the builder pattern here. It just makes the 40-arguments constructor private and have an additional class with getters and setters. To me this adds complexity in this case. If the arguments are just passed trough straight to the constructor then builder just adds another layer but no value.
As Dreamer pointed out it does not integrate easily into JPA either.

Answer (score 0):

***Is there any performance concern if too many parameter in a constructor?***  There is nothing to worry about in that regard, there is no performance concern regarding this.

This is because the overhead of the query execution itself (once it reaches the database) plus the network overhead involved in sending the query to the network and receiving the data back  is orders of magnitude higher than any penalty introduced by too many parameters in the constructor.

The reason to try to find an alternative would be code maintainability. You are probably in the presence of a highly denormalized table with many columns. This means that the database line can usually be split into several embeddables. The example bellow shows how 4 related columns could be grouped in an embeddable `Address` class:

```
@Entity
@Table("MANY_COLS_TABLE")
public class User {
   private Long id;
   @Embedded
   private Address address;
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String streetAdress;
    private int number;
    private String city;
    private ZipCode zipcode;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still, as practical situation like this: `SELECT new Constructor(<parameter list>) FROM EntityTable INNER JOIN EmbeddableTable;` I doubt if the decouple of the physical table can help reduce the constructor, especially when the embeddable object is a `@ElementCollection` Map, make it even more complex.